# Why didn't Eurus kill Doctor Watson in Sherlock?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

In the end of the *Sherlock* episode "The Lying Detective", we see Eurus expose herself to Doctor Watson and then shoot him with tranquilizers. As we see in the later episode she can kill anyone without hesitation.

My question is, why didn't she kill doctor Watson directly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Because telling Watson is the opening move in her "game".

She reveals herself to Watson that she is Sherlock's sister....so he can pass it on to Sherlock.

Of course, **she's insane so her methods are open to question** and, naturally, Sherlock still has to force Mycroft to confirm it but her end objective is to drag Sherlock into her web and torture him herself....with the whole truth.

Killing Watson would have hurt Sherlock but it wouldn't have been quite as much *fun* would it?

Plus, as we see later on, he's integral to the torture. Sherlock is forced to choose between killing his biological brother, Mycroft and his brother in adventure/life, Watson.

> Mycroft: "This is family"
>
> Sherlock: "That's why he stays!"

Comment: If she has killed Doctor Watson, Sherlock would have gone after her without waiting for Mycroft. Without Mycroft, It would have been easier for her to control Sherlock as well as the secret of jail governor won't be leaked.

Comment: Sherlock couldn't go after her as **he didn't know she existed** until Watson told him.

Comment: She could have planned a new cd with miss me title with Doctor Watson's body.

Comment: She could have walked in his front door and said "I'm your sister"....but she's **insane**. She chose to tell Sherlock by tricking his friend.